# Check whether files in a file list exist in a certain directory

Tags: file, bash, unix, scripting

The runtime arguments are as follows: `$1` is the path to the file containing the list of files
`$2` is the path to the directory containing the files
What I want to do is check that each file listed in `$1` exists in the `$2` directory

I'm thinking something like:

```
for f in 'cat $1'
  do
  if (FILEEXISTSIN$2DIRECTORY)
    then echo '$f exists in $2'
    else echo '$f is missing in $2' sleep 5 exit
  fi
done
```

As you can see, I want it so that if any of the files listed in `$1` don't exist in `$2` directory, the script states this then closes. The only part I can't get my head around is the (FILEEXISTSIN$2DIRECTORY) part. I know that you can do `[ -e $f ]`, but I don't know how you can make sure its checking that it exists in the $2 directory.

Edit: Thinking further upon this, perhaps I could use nested for loops?

Comment: What would the nested loop gain you?  Yes, if you can find a sane way of using them, you could use nested loops.  OTOH, for your question, there is no need for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your specified input file contains a newline-separated list of files to check, then the following solution (using a while read loop) is robust enough to handle file names with spaces properly.

Generally, you should never make use of a loop of the form `for i in $(command)`, and instead opt for a while loop.  See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor for more details.

```
while read -r file; do
   if [[ -e "$2/$file" ]]; then
      echo "$f exists in $2"
   else
      echo "$f does not exist in $2"
      sleep 5
      exit 1
   fi
done < "$1"
```

Comment: The file names contain no spaces, so I can break them up into individual files by using whitespace. In this instance, is using a for loop acceptable? If not, would I have to change anything in your code above to make it work properly?:)

Comment: If you are guaranteed that the filenames contain no whitespace characters, then an approach using for would work, but I still would not recommend it, it is a bad habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with a list of file names without spaces in the names (because the `$(cat $1)` notation will split things up like that), it is relatively straight forward:

```
for file in $(cat $1)
do
    if [ -e "$2/$file" ]
    then echo "$file exists in $2"
    else echo "$file is missing in $2"; sleep 5; exit 1
    fi
done
```

Basically, use the built-in string concatenation facilities to build the full path to the file, and use the `test` or `[` operator to check the files existence.

The complexities arise if you have to deal with arbitrary file names, especially if one of the arbitrary characters in an arbitrary file name can be the newline character.  Suffice to say, they complicate the issue sufficiently that I won't deal with it unless you say you need it dealt with, and even then, I'll negotiate on whether newlines in names need to be handled.  The double-quoted variable expansion is a key part of the strategy for dealing with it.  The other part of the problem is how to get the file names accurately into a variable.

Comment: This should work great. In your opinion, is using a for loop best for these types of procedures, or is a while loop better? Thank you once again.

Comment: To deal with file names except those containing newlines or leading or trailing blanks in the name, I'd probably use `while read file; do ...; done < input-file`. If you really have to deal with miscreants who use newlines or leading or trailing blanks in file names, then you have to work very hard. To preserve leading and trailing blanks, you can use `IFS=''; while read file; do ...; done < input-file`. I've never had to deal with sufficiently recalcitrant people; any such file names are one-off accidents that were renamed.